# Site shows an empty page and a 500 internal error

Tags: 7, .htaccess, wsod

My site doesn't show any page except an empty page. I changed the .htaccess file, but the sites shows a 500 server error.

What can I do?

The server log just shows the following line:

> [Tue Aug 27 12:07:52 2013] [error] [client 2.178.69.124] File does not exist: /home/pcctvir/public_html/favicon.ico

Comment: The error you have shown is for the little icon the browser places in the address bar. It is requested by the browser and has nothing to do with the production of the page by Drupal. Look for another error message, probably a PHP Error. If the only change you made was to .htaccess, try replacing the file with one from a fresh drupal install.

Comment: i replacing the file whit one from a new drupal core but not fix

Comment: If you do not have a PHP Error in your logs, try looking directly at the watchdog table. Scroll to the last entries and look for a PDO Exception.

Comment: tanks dear triskelion very very thankyou my problem is change the template.php file to a new template.php and problem is solved